# Mistakenly loading the same images multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have sprite sheet animations on prefabs, I made them using a script that has a Sprite[] array on them.
 It is declared like

```
private Sprite[] spriteSheet;
```

I have like 20 prefabs in the scene. As I'm not using a static variable here, does that mean I have loaded 20 images for each and every one of them? If so, using a static one would solve this to have only 1 array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if its not static, you have 20 different arrays. I would suggest using singleton class instead of static.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I hardly know anything about this singleton class :/ as I'm in a hurry, I would stick to what I know. So, would static solve this?

Comment: A relief, lucky I thought of this before finishing the game :D I accept your answer as soon as I can (it said 10 mins)

Comment: Almost forgot....
I load my sprites in the Start function using Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("location");
If I have this static, it will load only once, or 20 times with overwriting?

Comment: As you can see Start method is not static so it will run for every script in the scene. Thats why I suggested singleton class which should load sprites and all 20 scripts should use it.

Comment: Yeah, seems like no escape. By the way, 20 overwrites if I'm not mistaken? So no 20X memory usage. (Sure it will be slower, but prior to runtime it isn't as bad as when running)

Comment: Its like pressing Ctrl+C for 20 times.

Comment: A hacky work around could be to use an if guard, e.g. if (spriteSheet == null) load(...); This would prevent multiple loads